# Hierarchical subgrouping of bar charts in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Here is my data:

```
hiat    clasa   total
a.a I   26
a.e A   137
a.i A   122
a.î A   11
a.o A   49
a.u A   549
ă.i A   343
ă.o C   2
ă.u A   149
î.i C   162
î.u C   11
e.a D   326
e.e I   209
e.i A   230
e.î A   117
e.o C   591
e.u A   314
i.a D   1879
i.e D   5101
i.i I   101
i.î C   1
i.o D   1657
i.u C   423
o.a D   140
o.e C   138
o.i A   350
o.î A   3
o.o I   119
o.u A   27
u.a D   254
u.ă D   1
u.e D   59
u.i C   1125
u.o D   65
u.u I   21
```

I would want to group by clasa, and within each subgroup have the hierarchical order of hiat. The order of the groups should be A, D, C, I. The problem is that I don't know how to write the code. If you can help me with any suggestions, I would appreciate it.

I tried something like this :

```
library(ggplot2)
setwd("D:/PROIECTUL_DOCTORAL/CAPITOLUL_DE_FONOSTATISTICA/Rstat")
Data<- read.table ("hiat2.txt", sep="\t",header=TRUE)
Data <- data.frame (mygroup = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'), 
        mysubgroup = factor (c("a.u", "o.i", "ă.i", "e.u", "e.i", "ă.u", "a.e", "a.i", "e.î", "a.o", "o.u", "a.î", "o.î", "i.e", "i.a", "i.o", "e.a", "u.a", "o.a", "u.o", "u.e", "u.ă", "u.i", "e.o", "i.u", "î.i", "o.e", "î.u", "ă.o", "i.î", "e.e", "o.o", "i.i", "a.a", "u.u")), 
        total = c(549, 350, 343, 314, 230, 149, 137, 122, 117, 49, 27, 11, 3, 5101, 1879, 1657, 326, 254, 140, 65, 59, 1, 1125, 591, 423, 162, 138, 11, 2, 1, 209, 119, 101, 26, 21))
ggplot(Data, aes(x = reorder(mygroup, +total), y = total, fill = mysubgroup)) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.5, stat = "identity")
```

The resulting graph was not what I needed. The order of the groups should be A, D, C, I, and within each group, the bars should be displays from smallest to largest.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. What would be the desired output?

Comment: Try  `levels(Data$clasa)<-c("A","D","C","I")`
 and then `library(dplyr)` `Data%>%group_by(clasa)%>%arrange(clasa,hiat)`

Comment: Thank you! I haven't used dplyr until now, so I don't know exactly where to insert in my code what you suggested . I apologize for that. Could you pls walk me through it. Thank you. I'm rather new at R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
ggplot(Data1, aes(x = mygroup, y = reorder(total, mygroup), fill = mysubgroup)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", width = 0.5, stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
levels(df$clasa)<-c("A","D","C","I")
library(dplyr)
ordered=df%>%group_by(clasa)%>%arrange(clasa,hiat)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ordered)+geom_bar(aes(x=clasa,y=total,fill=hiat),stat = "identity",position="dodge")
```

Which gives:
[image]

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you for helping me!